# Save List<Integer> into sql

Tags: java, sql, list

How to save a list into sql? Assume the list contains {1,2,3,0,0} and I want them saved into table preferences,which has 5 column(pre1,pre2,pre3,pre4,pre5). How can I do that?

```
 public void addPre(List<Integer>preferences) throws Exception{
            DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
            Connection connect=db.getConnection();
            String sql="Insert into preferences(Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ";
            PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
            for(int i=0;i<preferences.size();i++)
            {

                    ps.setInt(i+1,preferences[i] );

            }
            ps.executeUpdate();
            connect.close();
            ps.close();
        }
```

Comment: Does this code throw an exception? Or what is the problem?

Comment: it highlights the preferences[i] and said that the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<Integer>....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
 ps.setInt(i+1,preferences[i] );
```

To

```
 ps.setInt(i+1,preferences.get(i) );
```

`preferences` is a `List` not an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access it using `preferences[i]`, it is list so it should be access like `preferences.get(i)`